# How to submit an app to the Apple App Store from Windows

Tags: android, ios, cordova, titanium

If I develop an app using Phonegap or Appcelerator Titanium on Windows and I
 want to submit my project to Apple Store, can I do it from Windows environment?

Using Windows:

- Can I create an Apple developer account?
- Can I submit the app to Apple Store?
- Can I build iOS project on Phonegap Build, for later submission on Apple Store?

I'm aware that an App Store license is $99 per year.

I know that for Android phones, Windows and Google Play have no problem, but not sure about iOS phones with Windows and the App Store.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Here are answers to your questions:**

1. Yes you can create an Apple developer account without an Apple device.
2. No, for the app to submit, you have to have Xcode, which will never be supported on Windows.
3. No you can't do that

Comment: thanks for your answer! Related with the 3rd question: so whats the point of Phonegap Build?

Comment: You can build any of iOS work on windows as they require xcode and xcode not supported by Windows

Comment: But at Phonegaps page they state: "Get app-store ready apps without the headache of maintaining native SDKs. PhoneGap Build will always be build against the required SDK for the platform you are targeting." [link here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_what_is_build.md.html#What%20is%20Build)

Comment: @user1907954 but i think you want to publish the ios app by your own and not Phonegap people doing for you. They will create a sandbox app for you which you can test on your windows machine but would never publish app on behalf of you.

Comment: Use a Mac cloud service such as macincloud.com. phonegap, cordova, Xcode are already installed on the servers. Basically you remote in from a Windows machine to a cloud Mac server for development. Works well for cross platform builds.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a service like Mac In The Cloud (http://www.macincloud.com/) to rent a VPS server and do it from there. It even comes preloaded with XCode.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a OSX Virtual Machine on Windows and then download and install Application Loader (or Xcode) on your OSX VM.

I can confirm this works.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here seem to be out of date. You can use the `iTMSTransporter.cmd` tool as such:

```
iTMSTransporter.cmd -assetfile myApp.ipa -u appDevUser -m upload  -assetDescription  descriptionFile
```

This accepts the IPA file and a description file which you should get from the tool vendor with the IPA.